# Telephony service error makes my activity hang while waiting to receive intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, telephony, telephonymanager

My main activity has a button which initiates a phone call via an intent.  My app then a has a broadcast receiver that detects when the device's phone state has changed to "OFF_HOOK".  The receiver then sends an intent to my main activity.  My main activity (which is "cemented" to the display by SYSTEM_TYPE_ERROR window layout parameter) then does an animation showing that a call has been initiated.  When the call ends, the broadcast receiver grabs the "IDLE" phone state, and sends an intent to my main activity so that my main activity can retract the animation to indicate that the call has ended. Some simple code:

Broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
       Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       // This flag allows the intent to be identified in the main activity  
        newIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_STATE,PhoneStateReceiver.STATE_ENDED_INCOMING_CALL);
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
     }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    int phoneState = intent.getIntExtra(PhoneCallReceiver.EXTRA_PHONE_STATE, -1);
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent called with phoneState = " + phoneState);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

The intent is then handled in onResume() depending on the data.

It works flawlessly on my personal Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop, which has active phone service.  On my old inactive phone (Nexus S on API 16) and on emulators I've tried through API 18 or 19 (which are obviously also inactive and incapable of making connecting phone calls), it does not work 90% of the time, even though I would expect it to work given that a phone call attempt is made (ringing and everything) that results in a standard phone service error message stating that my "account could not be validated".

In these error situations, the broadcast receiver receives the phone state change, prepares the intent, and does a context.startActivity(intent) directed to the main activity.  However, the main activity rarely receives the intent as it should.  Instead, the activity does not receive the intent until the phone call error message is completed and the device's telephone application ends.  Only then, my application suddenly receives the "OFF_HOOK" intent it was waiting for to indicate a call was placed, and immediately after receives the "IDLE" intent telling it to indicate the call has ended.  The "OFF_HOOK" intent is somehow getting hung.  In the 10% of the time that it works, I suspect the intent is just getting fired off in time before the system imposes some kind of freeze on my activity.

Does the device receive some special kind of system error message when it tries to make an outgoing call without a valid service account that locks up intents?

Comment: I had additional information, but SO seemed to think it was spam, so here we are...